# any pdf reader with annotation feature (open source)?

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a pdf reader for android which can also  annotate, select, highlight text. Any open source option?

Like [Foxit Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Foxit.Mobile.PDF)?

Comment: Why are you dropping Foxit?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Answer (score 3):

[Adobe Reader X for Android](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader-mobile.html) v10.3 now supports annotation, highlights and commenting. It is not open source, but it is free to the end user.

There are currently no open source Android PDF utilities that have worthwhile annotation features. This wiki page at the University of Massachusetts Boston lists several open source android PDF viewers, with links: http://howto.wikispaces.umb.edu/PDF+Annotation+with+Android

(I can't post a reply containing more than two links, my apologies.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader), and it has the features you need.

But I don't know what you mean by Open Source. Maybe FREE? If yes, ezPDF Reader has a *paid* and a somewhat reduced (but not free) *lite* version.

Comment: If you mean ezPDF Reader Lite as free, then you might be wrong. It is still a priced app though at 50% of the cost of the pro version.

Comment: @Narayanan Just checked; you're right. Lite is paid app. Was it ever free before? [Bought it Pro, though]

Comment: There is a ezPDF Reader API for Android that will cost you around $16K per year.

Comment: @geffchang: "don't know what you mean by Open Source."

See, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software). I'm not sure if this translation is any good, but, FWIW, "open source software" -> google translate -> "開源軟件"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an opensource pdf editor (and i don't know if you can find one with many features), but [Xodo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader) is a great free (but not opensource) pdf editor. I even like it more than ezPDF. **A while ago (2016/2017), I searched many pdf apps and xodo was the best one** in my opinion.